# SQL Deduplicate rows based on one Column

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have an ad name column and URL column, I just want to keep the unique ad name, with any of the URL variants. They are shortened varied URL but actually redirect to same URL.

How do I use SQL to return a table with unique ad names and its corresponding URL. I just need one URL for each ad.

| Ad name | URL |
| --- | --- |
| ad name 1 | URL variant 1 |
| ad name 1 | URL variant 2 |
| ad name 1 | URL variant 3 |
| ad name 2 | URL variant 1 |
| ad name 2 | URL variant 2 |
| ad name 2 | URL variant 3 |

Comment: What's the specific database?

Comment: I am using SQL in Google Bigquery

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the database, so I'll assume it's PostgreSQL.

You can do:

```
select distinct on (ad_name), ad_name, url from t order by ad_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by code below

SELECT ad_name, Max(URL) as URL
FROM  table
Group BY ad_name

Comment: Correct, you can use `MAX` or `MIN`. Even better would be `ANY_VALUE`, because this tells the DBMS that you really don't care and it can quickly pick just any of a name's URLs, without having to iterate through all its rows.